# Qt MinGW WIN32 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, mingw, console-application, windows

I have a project which was created for MinGW + Qt via cmake.
In CMakeLists.txt I have

```
add_executable (project-name WIN32 ${MOC_SRCS} ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES} ${RESOURCES} ${QtApp_RCC_SRCS})
```

If I try to compile it into VisualStudio 2010 I get the following linker error:

```
MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: undefined reference _WinMain@16 in func ___tmainCRTStartup
```

Then I erase WIN32

```
add_executable (project-name ${MOC_SRCS} ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES} ${RESOURCES} ${QtApp_RCC_SRCS})
```

The project compiles and works fine, but I have an a console window with a Qt window. How to disable the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `WIN32` within add_executable means your application will be of the type [SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). That is, an application which does not require a console. If this is specified then, rather than a `main(...)`, a [`WinMain(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which has different arguments from a main) is expected. Since your code most likely does not have this, you get the linker error you report.

Removing `WIN32` means your executable will be of the default type [SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which explains why your application works, but a console is shown.

So to fix it, do specify `WIN32` but change your `main()` to a `WinMain()`.

Comment: I have edited main() to a WinMain() like you say `code`#ifdef WIN32
int WinMain(int argc, char *argv[])
#else
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
#endif`code` but I have the same error? I have only one main() in project

Comment: It is not merely a change from `main` to `WinMain`. A `WinMain` has entirely different arguments. `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd );`

Comment: `int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)` worked! Thanks!